# When I create a new entry inside, it won't show up in the dietfacts menu instead it shows up in the default menu called product

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9

[Default Menu called "Product"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aURCy.jpg)

[Custom Menu called "DietFacts"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eywAd.jpg)

dietfacts_view.xml this is my xml file on which I very confused on why it wont get the data from the database and it displays nothing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>

<openerp>
   <data>

   <record id= "dietfacts_product_template_tree_view" model= "ir.ui.view">
   <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_tree_view" />
   <field name="model">product.template</field >
   <field name="arch" type= "xml">
         <field name="categ_id" position="before">
            <field name="servingsize"/>
             <field name="calories"/>

             <field name="lastupdated"/>
         </field>
   </field>
   </record>

    <record id= "dietfacts_product_template_form_view" model= "ir.ui.view">
   <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view" />
   <field name="model">product.template</field >
   <field name="arch" type= "xml">
         <field name="list_price" position="after">

             <field name="calories"/>
             <field name="servingsize"/>
             <field name="lastupdated"/>


         </field>
   </field>
   </record>
      <record id="product.product_template_action_dietfacts" model= 
"ir.actions.act_window" >
        <field name="name" >Diet Items</field >
        <field name="type" >ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model" >product.template</field >
        <field name="view_mode" >tree,kanban,form</field >
        <field name="view_type" >form</field >
        <field name="view_id" ref= "product.product_template_tree_view" />
        <field name="context" >{"search_default_filter_to_sell":1}</field>
        <field name="domain">[('categ_id.name','=','Diet Items')]</field>
        <field name="help" type= "html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create" >
                Click to define a new product.
            </p><p>
                You must define a product for everything you sell, whether 
it's a physical product, a consumable or a service you offer to  customers.             
            </p><p>
                The product form contains information to simplify the sale 
process: price, notes in the quotation, accounting data, procurement 
methods, etc.
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>

     <menuitem action= "product.product_template_action_dietfacts"
        id="menu_product_template_action_dietfacts"
        parent="base.menu_sales" sequence= "14" />


       </data>
</openerp>
```

dietfacts.py here is my dietfacts.py file

```
    #Dietfatcs Application
from openerp import models, fields

class Dietfacts_product_template(models.Model):
    _name = 'product.template'
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    calories = fields.Integer("Calories")
    nutrients = fields.Integer("Nutrients")
    proteins = fields.Integer("Proteins")
```

**openerp**.py this is my openerp file

```
    {
    'name' : "DietFacts",
    'version' : "1.0",
    'author' : "Greg Moss, OdooClass.com",
    'description' : 'Food is life', 
    'depends' : ['sale'],
    'data' : ['dietfacts_view.xml'],
    'installable' : True,
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem in this domain.[('categ_id.name','=','Diet Items')] can you please check whether the product having a category with an exact name as 'Diet Items'.

Comment: Finally Solve it

i change the domain to

[('dietitems','=',True)]